# How were art assets created in the late 16-bit/early 32-bit era?

Tags: assets, art, asset-creation

How were 2d and 3d art assets typically created in the early-to-mid 1990's (16-bit and 32-bit eras?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For 2D, [Deluxe Paint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deluxe_Paint) was pretty popular in those days.

For 3D, [3D Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodesk_3ds_Max) was around on the PC (eventually becomming Autodesk 3D Studio Max later in it's life). On the Amiga you had [Lightwave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightwave) (which was also used for TV and film).

Comment: Whoa - DPaint - what a great app that was!

Comment: I can remember using DPaint, and I was born late 1994. Wow I feel old.

Comment: 3d studio and 3d studio max are completely separate programs. But that's nitpicking..

Comment: @Jari - According to it's Wikipedia entry it was a rewrite and re-name, that's not completely separated - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3ds_Max#Early_history_and_releases

Comment: Well, if I remember correctly, max was actually built by a separate company which they acquired, but I may remember wrong. Regardless, when you "rewrite and rename" something, there's not much left, except marketing. And yes, I did say this is all just nitpicking.